# How to predict a sequence in Keras with multidimensional input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I do have the following problem:
I want to predict 5 sequences of 30 days each for a two-dimensional input (X_test) as seen below.

```
        ### This is X_test ###

array([[[0.9889562 , 0.35528348],
        [0.98835297, 0.36100796],
        [0.98943452, 0.39090311],
        [0.97700769, 0.37543382],
        [0.96866762, 0.34993568]],

       [[0.98835297, 0.36100796],
        [0.98943452, 0.39090311],
        [0.97700769, 0.37543382],
        [0.96866762, 0.34993568],
        [0.9680748 , 0.3501392 ]],

       [[0.98943452, 0.39090311],
        [0.97700769, 0.37543382],
        [0.96866762, 0.34993568],
        [0.9680748 , 0.3501392 ],
        [0.96594827, 0.37902433]],

       ...,

       shape(150,5,2)
```

My LSTM model code looks as follows (2 input features at 5 timesteps, 1 output):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100,activation = "relu", return_sequences = True,input_shape = (5,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(100,activation = "relu", return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")
```

So far I only had a 1-dimensional input and used the following code for predicting a 30 day sequence, which worked totally fine:

```
import numpy

def pred_multi(test_data, start_sequence_day, sequence_length):

  predictedsequence = []
  test_data1 = test_data[start_sequence_day] #Used X_test as test_data

  for i in range(sequence_length):
    test_data1 = test_data1.reshape(1,5,2) 
    prediction = model.predict(test_data1)
    predictedsequence.append(prediction)

    test_data1 = numpy.insert(test_data1, len(test_data1[0]), prediction)
    test_data1 = numpy.delete(test_data1, 0, axis = 0)

  return predictedsequence
```

However, since I do now have another input feature this code is not working properly as I do only get one output. However, I need two inputs for the next timestep as an input.

Does anyone can help? I tried everything but I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your input have to be fixed-size in Keras unfortunatey, however, you could have an **input of size 2** and **pad it** with 0 for when you have an input of size 1.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So when I want the model to predict both values (since pad it with 0 would distort the output and is not helpful in my case) the only option is to change the model itself so it produces to outputs?

Comment: If you add an **end of sequence** tag after your output, it won't distort your output I think, the network will simply learn when to stop.